# How to flag spam user profiles in the absence of posts to flag?

Tags: support, flags, profile-page, spam

I came across [this user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12255472/gracia-thomas?tab=profile), which contains links to the website of some sort of tv streaming service. A [quick google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22With%20great%20passion%20for%20writing,%20I%20started%20writing%20short%20stories%20and%20essay%22) revealed that the same text and links have been posted to dozens of websites that allow people to create user profiles or post messages that are exposed to search engines, using different names and [stock images](https://www.freepik.com/free-photo/blue-eyes-wavy-modern-one-beautiful_1069675.htm#page=1&position=9).

However, since this user has not posted any questions, answers or comments on Stack Overflow, it is impossible to flag them. How would I go about flagging this user profile as spam?

*(And also, do we have an automated process to find such spam profiles?)*

Comment: @WeareMonica. As usual those questions didn't show up in the possible duplicates window while I was writing this question.

Comment: Btw, I was looking through recently created accounts named Thomas, looking for my nephew who just started CS studies. There isn't really any other way to "discover" this kind of inactive user.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to flag a user if they have no visible content (posts / comments).

The current guidance instructs you to flag one of your own posts and explain the situation in the flag text. This is IMO an acceptable workaround (it's official!) before there's ability to flag a user directly.

Comment: Note that there's nothing wrong with providing a link to a website in your profile.A profile needs to be particularly egregious (offensive) to be removed. Advertising in a profile is fine—just not in a post. Even if this particular profile were to be flagged, it likely would be rejected.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica Even if the profile was created solely for the purpose of spam?

Comment: @m69 How could you determine that was the purpose if nothing had been posted by it, as asked in this question using the example user profile?

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica The pattern of the same info being used in dozens of non-active profiles on other sites? I agree it requires a level of detective work that's outside the scope of SE moderation.